# systemd-boot setup: Failed to write 'LoaderSystemToken' EFI variable: Invalid argument

Tags: uefi, 23.10, systemd-boot

I installed Ubuntu Server 23.10 on a remote system from a bootable flash drive using debootstrap and chroot. When I run bootctl-install, this error comes up:

```
Failed to write 'LoaderSystemToken' EFI variable: Invalid argument
```

And when I try to update or install sofware:

```
Failed to write 'LoaderSystemToken' EFI variable: Invalid argument
dpkg: error processing package systemd-boot (--configure):
 installed systemd-boot package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 systemd-boot
needrestart is being skipped since dpkg has failed
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

As far as I can tell, it doesn't break anything, the system boots fine etc, but it does interfere with the dpkg process. Everything else I've found online related to this error appears to deal with setting up a VPS. How can I get rid of these errors?